# template friend redefinition error that works with clang but not g++

Tags: c++, templates, g++, clang, friend

I have the following code:

```
template<typename E, typename M, bool treeIsLeft>
class Digit ... {
  ...
  friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Digit<E, M, true> const& d){
      ...
  }
  friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Digit<E, M, false> const& d){
      ...
  }

}
```

When compiled with Clang, it works as it should, but with g++ 4.9 I get two errors that say

```
../src/fingertree.h:399:26: error: redefinition of 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Digit<std::basic_string<char>, int, true>&)'
     friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Digit<E, M, true> const& d){
                          ^
../src/fingertree.h:399:26: note: 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Digit<std::basic_string<char>, int, true>&)' previously defined here
../src/fingertree.h:402:26: error: redefinition of 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Digit<std::basic_string<char>, int, false>&)'
     friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, Digit<E, M, false> const& d){
                          ^
../src/fingertree.h:402:26: note: 'std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, const Digit<std::basic_string<char>, int, false>&)' previously defined here
```

Have I done something wrong? How can I make it work with g++?

Edit: 
I found out how to make it work: I have to move the definitions outside the class body, and retain only declarations within. Also I have to insert template<...> specifiers. However that feels unnecessarily verbose and unnatural and I still would like to know what was wrong about defining the friends inside the class.

Comment: Can't seem to repeat the problem.

Comment: Sorry for the wrong answer.